# Solr or SolrCloud in Aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, solr, amazon-ec2, solrcloud

I have to add a solr search server in an Aws-EC2 instance.Right now I have Solr installed in an AWS-EC2 instance with ram 8gb and disc space 50gb.Its working fine, but I was wondering if changing to SolrCloud improve the performance.Should I go for normal Solr or Should I go for SolrCloud? If SolrCloud,why?

Comment: What is your requirement?

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to say, both will work. ["Regular" Solr allows you to scale your infrastructure by adding replicas for your cores, while SolrCloud adds hidden complexity for easier handling of replication and query distribution](https://support.lucidworks.com/hc/en-us/articles/201298317-What-is-SolrCloud-And-how-does-it-compare-to-master-slave-).

If everything works now, I wouldn't fret it. Keep track of your query times and re-evaluate if you run into issues where you need to add instances to your cluster quickly. A regular, simple Solr setup with HTTP replication will in almost all cases do just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Both would work, but if you were starting afresh, go with SolrCloud. Here's a few reasons for it:

1. There is little or no meaningful application development overhead if you go with SolrCloud. If you are writing your integration / application to talk to Solr, just do so with SolrCloud to begin with.
2. SolrCloud is what's getting more and more utilized by everyone and lot of new development and capabilities are release fast enough.
3. As you scale, you are already on a path to simple scalability as opposed to trying to figure out High Availability and / or Data partitioning. You could use SolrCloud API to add replicas, etc.
4. Not much too lose from a feature, functionality perspective.

If you want to try out starting a cluster with high availability or single node deployment of SolrCloud on AWS, you can sign up for a free trial at https://searchstax.measuredsearch.com/freetrial/